# Hard time with running Proguard using android maven plugin for obfuscating apklib

Tags: android, maven-plugin, proguard

I am looking to obfuscate non public methods etc in the android apklib file so that I can distribute the apklib file with other people without compromising on sharing all my source code since apklib contain the source code.

The approach I am taking is to obfuscate non public methods in the library project by enabling the proguard.cfg in pom.xml

Here is how my proguard.cfg looks like

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Here is the error I am getting on Maven install

> [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.3.2:generate-sources
>   (default-generate-sources) @ libraryprojects-lib1 --- [INFO]
>   ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0 [INFO] ANDROID-904-002:
>   Found aidl files: Count = 0 [INFO]
>   C:\GSDevelopment\tools\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe [package,
>   -m, -J, C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\generated-sources\r,
>   -M, C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\AndroidManifest.xml,
>   -S, C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\res,
>   --auto-add-overlay, -A, C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\assets,
>   -I, C:\GSDevelopment\tools\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar]
>   [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
>   (default-resources) @ libraryprojects-lib1 --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8'
>   encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 1 resource [INFO]
>   skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\generated-sources\extracted-dependencies\src\main\resources
>   [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile
>   (default-compile) @ libraryprojects-lib1 --- [INFO] Compiling 2 source
>   files to
>   C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\classes
>   [INFO]  [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.3.2:proguard
>   (default-proguard) @ libraryprojects-lib1 --- [INFO]
>   C:\GSDevelopment\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\bin\java [-Xmx512M, -jar,
>   C:\GSDevelopment\tools\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib\proguard.jar,
>   @proguard.cfg, -injars,
>   'C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\classes',
>   -libraryjars, 'C:\GSDevelopment\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\lib\rt.jar',
>   -libraryjars, 'C:\GSDevelopment\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\lib\jsse.jar',
>   -libraryjars, 'C:\GSDevelopment\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_33\jre\lib\jce.jar',
>   -libraryjars, c:.m2GSD\repository\com\google\android\android\4.0.1.2\android-4.0.1.2.jar(!org/xml/**,!org/w3c/**,!java/**,!javax/**), -libraryjars, 'c:.m2GSD\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar',
>   -libraryjars, 'c:.m2GSD\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.1\httpclient-4.0.1.jar',
>   -libraryjars, 'c:.m2GSD\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\httpcore-4.0.1.jar',
>   -libraryjars, 'c:.m2GSD\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar',
>   -libraryjars, 'c:.m2GSD\repository\org\khronos\opengl-api\gl1.1-android-2.1_r1\opengl-api-gl1.1-android-2.1_r1.jar',
>   -libraryjars, 'c:.m2GSD\repository\xerces\xmlParserAPIs\2.6.2\xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar',
>   -libraryjars, 'c:.m2GSD\repository\xpp3\xpp3\1.1.4c\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar', -libraryjars, 'c:.m2GSD\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar',
>   -outjars, 'C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\proguard-obfuscated.jar',
>   -dump, 'C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\proguard\dump.txt',
>   -printseeds, 'C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\proguard\seeds.txt',
>   -printusage, 'C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\proguard\usage.txt',
>   -printmapping, 'C:\GSDevelopment\expworkspace\Samples\libraryprojects\libraryprojects-lib1\target\proguard\mapping.txt']
>   [INFO] Note: there were 185 duplicate class definitions. [INFO]
>   ***java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the
>   proper '-keep' options? [INFO]    at
>   proguard.shrink.Shrinker.execute(Shrinker.java:159) [INFO]    at
>   proguard.ProGuard.shrink(ProGuard.java:275) [INFO]    at
>   proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:101) [INFO]   at
>   proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)***

I have two java files with two private methods. Can anyone point me what may be going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you still need an answer, but I'll give it anyway, because I ran into similar problem and stumbled upon your question...

The key point is that, to quote Proguard manual: "In order to determine which code has to be preserved and which code can be discarded or obfuscated, you have to specify one or more entry points to your code. These entry points are typically classes with main methods, applets, midlets, activities, etc."

So, it looks like you didn't have any public entries into your code. There has to be a public entry, otherwise how can anything use your library or how can OS (like Android) call into your code.

You need to identify what the entry points into your library are and then need to make sure that "-keep" commands are used appropriately. For example, from Proguard example for the libraries, this is how they keep public classes:

```
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```